# why dynamic button added to grid layout have a lot of distance between each other?

Tags: c++, css, qt

I make an application in Qt. In mainwindow.cpp I have a frame to show another widget. this widget fills by QPushButton from code behind (with the data in data base). the maximum button count is 8. this code create buttons from database:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < btnlst.count(); ++i)
    {
        QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(this);
        //b->setGeometry(0,10,100,100);
        b->setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0.682, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.142857 rgba(220, 0, 22, 255), stop:0.980296 rgba(216, 74, 73, 255), stop:1 rgba(217, 73, 73, 255));border:none ;color:white;");
        b->setText(btnlst[i]);
        if(mood=="Frame")
        {
            QSize size(55,55);
            b->setMinimumSize(size);
            b->setMaximumSize(size);
            b->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum));
            ui->gridLayout->addWidget(b,0,i,Qt::AlignVCenter);
        }
        else
        {
            QSize size(70,70);
            b->setMinimumSize(size);
            b->setMaximumSize(size);
            b->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum));
            if(i<4)
                ui->gridLayout->addWidget(b,0,i,Qt::AlignVCenter);
            else
              ui->gridLayout->addWidget(b,0,i-3,Qt::AlignVCenter);
        }
        //after creates buttons

        connect(b,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Function()));
        btn << b;

    }
    ui->gridLayout->setSpacing(0);
```

I fixed the widget size with maximum(750,150) and minimum(600,150). This is my widget (I use vertical layout in main widget):
[image]
this is my result in embedded device:
[image]
As you see I set black color for widget and set group box white color. but the black color is not show in frame and also there is a lot of space between each button. I create 8 buttons but just show 5 button for me in my frame.
How can I reduce the space between each buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set alignment to the layout by calling `layout->setAlignment(...)`. Here is a working example of aligning them to the center. You can also use `Qt::AlignRight` or `Qt::AlignLeft` if you want.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

class MyWidget : public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QGroupBox(parent)
    {
        setTitle("GROUP BOX");
        setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0.682,"
                      "x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.142857 rgba(220, 0, 22, 255),"
                      "stop:0.980296 rgba(216, 74, 73, 255),"
                      "stop:1 rgba(217, 73, 73, 255));"
                      "border:none; color:white;}");
        QGridLayout *grid_layout = new QGridLayout;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
            button->setFixedSize(80, 80);
            button->setText("Button");
            grid_layout->addWidget(button, 0, i);
        }
        grid_layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        grid_layout->setSpacing(1);
        setLayout(grid_layout);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyWidget widget;
    widget.resize(800, 200);
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Result:
[image: Result image]